# Find previous day in the Dataframe and assign its value to current day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Dataframe which has values corresponding to date. Now i need to get previous day column values and assign to the current day.

Ex:- Current day is 10-01-2020 then previous day in the dataframe is 07-01-2020, get the values of previous day and assign to current.

### Sample input

```
Date       Sales    zone_Total
2/5/2019    277.08  358.4
2/5/2019    277.08  358.4
2/5/2019    277.08  358.4
2/5/2019    277.08  358.4
2/5/2019    277.08  358.4
3/5/2019    567.95  320.68
3/5/2019    567.95  320.68
3/5/2019    567.95  320.68
3/5/2019    567.95  320.68
6/5/2019    1305.16 -556.48
6/5/2019    1305.16 -556.48
6/5/2019    1305.16 -556.48
6/5/2019    1305.16 -556.48
6/5/2019    1305.16 -556.48
6/5/2019    1305.16 -556.48
```

### Sample output

```
Date    Sales   zone_Total
2/5/2019    NA  NA
2/5/2019    NA  NA
2/5/2019    NA  NA
2/5/2019    NA  NA
2/5/2019    NA  NA
3/5/2019    277.08  358.4
3/5/2019    277.08  358.4
3/5/2019    277.08  358.4
3/5/2019    277.08  358.4
6/5/2019    567.95  320.68
6/5/2019    567.95  320.68
6/5/2019    567.95  320.68
6/5/2019    567.95  320.68
6/5/2019    567.95  320.68
6/5/2019    567.95  320.68
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. Its considered good practice to include what you tried to achieve the desired output and what did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` on `Date` and aggregate te dataframe using `last`, next use `reindex` to conform aggregated DataFrame to the index according the dates in original datafarme:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Date').last().shift().reindex(df['Date']).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
print(df1)

        Date   Sales  zone_Total
0   2/5/2019     NaN         NaN
1   2/5/2019     NaN         NaN
2   2/5/2019     NaN         NaN
3   2/5/2019     NaN         NaN
4   2/5/2019     NaN         NaN
5   3/5/2019  277.08      358.40
6   3/5/2019  277.08      358.40
7   3/5/2019  277.08      358.40
8   3/5/2019  277.08      358.40
9   6/5/2019  567.95      320.68
10  6/5/2019  567.95      320.68
11  6/5/2019  567.95      320.68
12  6/5/2019  567.95      320.68
13  6/5/2019  567.95      320.68
14  6/5/2019  567.95      320.68
```